# Swapping unknown number of balls from two drawers based on a coin toss

Tags: probability, statistics

There are n balls labeled with at least one person's name. The balls are distributed in two drawers, with drawer 1 containing more balls.

Each person tosses a fair coin,
if the outcome is heads, the person must put all the balls with their name from drawer 1 into drawer 2 and put the balls with their name from drawer 2 into drawer 1. Basically the balls are taken from both drawers and placed in the respective other one.

Show that after each person tosses a coin, there is a positive probability that there are more balls in drawer 2 than in drawer 1.

I encountered this problem in my textbook and don't know how to approach this question.

Comment: $1$ in a $10^{10}$ is still a positive probability...

Comment: Not sure the question is clear.  I took it to mean "regardless of the distribution of names..." in which case the answer is No.  But on re-reading it seems more likely that you intended the names to be part of the probability (so that you aren't concerned about pathological configurations).  But in that case, the answer seems to be clearly Yes since there is some chance that a given player's name is on every ball in drawer one and that they throw $H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a positive probability $2^{-n}$ that each coin toss results in swapping. In that case, all balls are swapped, and since there were initially more balls in drawer $1$, there are then more balls in drawer $2$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i translated the text to English. If the outcome is tails nothing happens. By "vice versa" I meant that the person must put all the balls with their name from drawer 1 into drawer 2 and put the balls with their name from drawer 2 into drawer 1. Basically the balls are taken from both drawers and placed in the respective other one.

Comment: @Alina: I updated my answer according to your clarification of the question.